# How to display the highlighted typeahead value in the inputbox in ngxTypeahead?

Tags: jquery, angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

This is official ngxTypeahead plunker

http://embed.plnkr.co/gV6kMSRlogjBKnh3JHU3/

Here in this, when we press keyUp or keyDown ,the i need to display the highlighted(which is blue in color)  typeahead option's innerHTML in the input box similar to firefox search box typeahead.
How can i do that?

So i have this issue in implementing the above

Using jquery i can get my target element like this

```
var target= $(this).siblings().find("li.active");
```

Now i'm getting like this

This is my onKeyUp function

```
onKeyUp($event.key){
     if( $event.keyCode== '38'|| $event.keyCode == '40'){
     var target= $event.srcElement.nextElementSibling.children[4].children[0].innerText;
     }
}
```

So if i keep debugger inside Onkey($event.key) function

and type this `$event.srcElement.nextElementSibling.children`

```
0:div.typeahead-backdrop

1:button.list-group-item

2:button.list-group-item

3:button.list-group-item

4:button.list-group-item.active

5:button.list-group-item
```

I get like above.
So i need to get the active button innerText. Inside the button it has a span and i need it's innerHTML.
Is there any specific simple way to access above target using angular2?

Comment: Could you give some context about what you're trying to *achieve*? Are you setting that class in the template? Why do you need access to that element?

Comment: Where your target come from ? Input form ? If yes you can get the Value using (keyUp) event handler

Comment: @jonrsharpe I edited by question

Comment: @andrea06590 I edited my question can you check now?

Comment: But why is any of that necessary? What is setting the active class? Why do you need access to the element; what are you getting from its content? As a rule, accessing the DOM via the $event is an anti-pattern: https://angular.io/guide/user-input#passing-event-is-a-dubious-practice.

Comment: Ok you want to check which button is active add a (click) function on each button. When you click on the button change its state using a map or a two dimensional array < buttonName, state >

Comment: I'm using ngxtypeahead and it is setting 'active class' on hover . So i need to display the data which is highlighted in the input box. So i need to pick the highlighted button span and display the innerHTML of it in the inputbox.

Comment: @andrea06590 I cant add function in the button. I'm using ngxtypeahead

Comment: Surely that library gives you easier access to the value than that?! Aren't you binding to `taSelected` per [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-typeahead#outputs)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe We can use that 'Onclick' of the selected element. I need to get ' onHover' value.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do, or why. It's likely an http://xyproblem.info

Comment: Okay let me ask clearly

Comment: http://embed.plnkr.co/gV6kMSRlogjBKnh3JHU3/ This is official ngxTypeahead plunker. So when typeahead opens, if we use keyUp or keyDown it will move through the typeahead options. So i need to display the highlighted typeahead option's innerText which has blue background in the inputbox. This is my problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**EDIT :**

Add a reference on the input #ngxTypeahead and create a viewchild in app.ts code (import from angular core)

```
  @ViewChild("ngxTypeahead") ngxTypeahead: any;
   // then simply access the values using this.ngxTypeahead;
```

See my screenshot with console log in the select function :) https://ibb.co/ehnfgS

Comment: Don't hesitate to explain the downvote as my answer is a correct one.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer. Can you please update here in this. http://embed.plnkr.co/gV6kMSRlogjBKnh3JHU3/  I need to display the highlighted typeahead option's innerHTML in the inputbox when we do keyUp or keyDown. If you update the plunker i'll understand better. Thanks in advance @andrea

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got it now. Screenshot is helpful.

Comment: You are welcome, but your question would be how to access my ngxAhead component information. Best